# Hexadecimal base conversion with max 4 digits

Tags: php, hex

I have a problem understanding the hexadecimal conversion in PHP.

Now i have the number `-2.09`. I want to convert it to hexa but the length of the result should be 4. So the result should be `FFFE`, but it gives me `FFFFFFFE` instead.

What is the function to be used in order to give me just 4 digits hexadecimal?

Currently I am using just this function to convert:

`dechex(-2)`

Comment: What code have you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are totally sure that you will only need 4 bytes to store your number, you can use `substr` to retrieve the part you need:

```
   $a = dechex(-2);
=> "fffffffffffffffe"
   substr($a, -4);
=> "fffe"
```

Comment: but that does not change the decimal value?.

Answer (score 0):

A negative number needs more bits to store its value in hexadecimal version, because also the `-` sign must be stored.

So, you can't store the number `-2.09` in a 4 length hexadecimal representation, nor the `-2` number:

Example:

```
echo dechex((float)-2.09);
echo "\n";
echo dechex(-2);
```

Output:

```
fffffffe
fffffffe
```

[demo](https://eval.in/955467)